# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence while setting initial condition for an array in python

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array `B`which is `4*1`. I want to set its last column as the initial condition for my new array `W` defined as
`W[:,0]=LA.inv(v).dot(B[:,-1])` where `v` is another matrix of order `4*4`.
But it shows up value error.
How do I do this then?

Comment: Please show full code (minimal working example) and the error message.